# How to use one code for multiple spreadsheets that can be updated, attempt to use Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have 200+ spreadsheet that our customers fill. I developed a script to manage the spreadsheets which is basically identical in function.

The problem is when I modify the script I need to change it in all these sheets. I tried using libraries but with no success and I hoping to hear if someone knows an answer.

The library version I include (with development on) in each spreadsheet does not show the change ensued. It will only show the results at the time of inclusion, which means that in order to make this work I have to go to each of the spreadsheets, remove the library and re-install the most recent version. The updated library only works from my owner's account. The library is of course shared by anyone who has a link.
Running a library's updated function in any of the spreadsheets produce an error:
    "TypeError: Cannot find function FunctionName in object [object Object]. (line 2, file "test")"

Is there a good way to have all spreadsheets same one code that I can change whenever I wish?

Comment: Your library needs "Anyone can edit" sharing permission if that's not already set, but are you able to share some sample code from your library and slave scripts that isn't getting updated?

Comment: Seems like this is not yet possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500764/is-it-possible-to-have-one-script-for-multiple-spreadsheets

Comment: I suggest we all go star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1356&q=type%3DEnhancement%20library&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Comment: @BryanP 
The script file "ManifestManager" has the following:
    function ShowMessage(){
    Browser.msgBox("You have correct settings")
    }
</pre>
In the spreadsheet
    function myFunction() {
      ManifestManager.ShowMessage()
    }

The output shows a message box "You have correct settings." If I deleted the entire function "ShowMessage" the reference to the library ManifestManager.ShowMessage() would still show the message box even if the function has been deleted

Answer (score 1):

You should turn on "development mode". Resources -> libraries included for each spreasheet that include the library

Comment: "development mode" is on. It does not do anything actually.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had much success using library myself.

One solution I would suggest would be to use a standalone script. If the spreadsheets have identical features, you can run the script on all of them using a for loop.

You can get an array of files inside a folder using using getFiles()

```
// Logs the number of files in the 'kittens' folder
 var folder = DocsList.getFolder('kittens');
 var files = folder.getFiles();
 Logger.log(files.length);
```