# Use same .gs script for many Spreadsheet files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some consultation

I'm working woth Google Sheets. I have a lot of SpreadSheets. And I need an additional functionality for them, I need addition menu that will show me `Hello everyone` alert. Good I can write a `.gs` script for that and I did it. But now I need to copy this script to all of my Spreadsheets one by one. And If I want to modify the script - I had to do this in every document :(

Is there any wway to use same `.gs` script in multiple google document?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use one code for multiple spreadsheets that can be updated, attempt to use Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797028/how-to-use-one-code-for-multiple-spreadsheets-that-can-be-updated-attempt-to-us)

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish it as [Sheets add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/). [image: Deploy as Sheets web add-on]

Then you can install in in all of your sheets.  Any updates you publish thereafter will propagate out to the installed instances.